# SQLite database gets corrupted

Tags: java-native-interface, database-connection, android-sqlite

when i use cursor.getCount() or cursor.moveToFirst() and no records are fetched from the db

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.native_fill_window(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:75)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:295)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:276)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:171)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:248)
```

Someone suggest that Using multiple instances of SQLiteDatabase could be causing my problem if i have two instances updating the same database file at the same time.So for that i have checked each and every instance of db connection but nothing helps. :(

I just want to handle the exception before deleting the db.

So guys pls suggest something which resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if the DB gets corrupted you just replace the database with a backup. You can use simple file copy paste methods to maintain a backup each day.

Comment: Thanks yushi but this way will handle the futher working of the app means next time the app is opened :)